# In Lua, a variable is unexpectedly nil

Tags: loops, lua

I have programmed a 'punishbox' (to punish a player for rulebreaking) for my Crysis Wars server mod but for some reason I keep getting this error:

> [Warning] [Lua Error] scripts/functions.lua:340: attempt to perform arithmetic on global     'tme' (a nil value)

But the thing is, `tme` is actually a number value between 0 and 15. The below code basically sets up the 'punishbox' and checks if it's still valid for the player or not. As you can see, `tme` is actually a value (if it was not, the code would not run at all). Am I doing something wrong here?

As this is a specific situation, I can't find that much on the internet. `tme` is referenced from `time`, which is forwarded to the function by a chat command and is definitely a number.

Also, is there any simpler way of doing this?

Code:

```
function XPunishPlayer(Name, time, reason)
    if (time > 5) then
        System.LogAlways("[SYSTEM] Punished by administrator: "..Name:GetName().."");
    end
    if (not Msg) then
        local tme = math.floor(time*60);
        Msg = true;
        XMessageChatToPlayer(Name, "[!punish] You were punished for "..time.." minutes:    "..reason.."");
        g_gameRules.game:RenamePlayer(Name.id, "[PUNISH]"..Name:GetName().."");
        XMessageChatToPlayer(Name, "[!punish] You can use !pm to dispute this punishment.");
        g_gameRules:KillPlayer(Name);
    end
    Script.SetTimer( 1000,function()
        local tme = tme+1;
        XPunishPlayer(Name, time, reason);
        Name.actor:SetNanoSuitEnergy(0);
        local punish = math.floor(timeleft-1);
        g_gameRules.onClient:ClStepWorking(g_gameRules.game:GetChannelId(Name.id), tme);
        if (tme == math.floor(time*60)) then
            g_gameRules.onClient:ClStepWorking(g_gameRules.game:GetChannelId(Name.id), false);
            XMessageChatToPlayer(Name, "[!punish] Released from the punishbox.");
            XMessageInfoToAll("Unpunished "..Name:GetName()..", was punished for "..time.."     minutes: "..reason.." (Server Administration)");
            return;
        end
    end);
end
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly. This is really hard to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `tme` is defined in an if block, in Lua every block creates its own closure, and so the value of `tme` is local to that block.

You can either make it a global variable by simply removing the `local` keyword (this is usually not a good idea) or define it before the block like this:

```
function XPunishPlayer(Name, time, reason)
    if (time > 5) then
        System.LogAlways("[SYSTEM] Punished by administrator: "..Name:GetName().."");
    end
    local tme;
    if (not Msg) then
        tme = math.floor(time*60);
        [...]
    end
    Script.SetTimer( 1000,function()
        tme = tme-1;
        [...]
    end);
end
```

I am also quite sure the second `local tme` inside your `SetTimer` would have given you another headache...

Comment: Scoping in Lua (It's Lua, not LUA btw., it's not an abbreviation) is actually quite straight forward. You may want to read up on it [in the manual here](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.4.7) and [especially here](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.6). Correct indentation helps a lot though ;)

Comment: One of the ways consistent indentation helps is to make the scope of basic blocks clear, and that will make the scope of a local variable clear as well. In short, a local is in scope from the point where it is declared until the end of the block containing that declaration (with a special quirk that allows `repeat local done=true until done` to do what it obviously means). Without indentation it is harder to spot this kind of error.

Comment: nitpicking: every block defines an scope, not a closure.  Of course, a closure is a block, and therefore, a scope.